# How to run a Laravel Job at specify Queue

Tags: laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.1, task-queue, laravel-queue

I have a Job to perform send SMS to user. I want to run this job on the specify queue-name. For example, this job added to "**SMS**" queue. So I found a way to do this but it's exists some errors.

**Create job instance and use onQueue() function to do this**:

```
    $resetPasswordJob = new SendGeneratedPasswordResetCode(app()->make(ICodeNotifier::class), [
        'number' => $user->getMobileNumber(),
        'operationCode' => $operationCode
    ]);

    $resetPasswordJob->onQueue('SMS');

    $this->dispatch($resetPasswordJob);
```

My Job class like this:

```
class SendGeneratedPasswordResetCode implements ShouldQueue
{
   use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

/**
 * The code notifier implementation.
 *
 * @var ICodeNotifier
 */
protected $codeNotifier;

/**
 * Create the event listener.
 *
 * @param ICodeNotifier $codeNotifier
 * @return self
 */
public function __construct(ICodeNotifier $codeNotifier)
{
    $this->codeNotifier = $codeNotifier;
}

/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    echo "bla blaa bla";
    #$this->codeNotifier->notify($event->contact->getMobileNumber(), $event->code);
}

public function failed()
{
    var_dump("failll");
}
}
```

So I type this command to console:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=SMS --tries=1
```

But this error message I get when executes this job:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>
> No handler registered for command [App\Services\Auth\User\Password\SendGeneratedPasswordResetCode]

**Note**: Other way is add event to EventServiceProvider's **listen** property and fire the event. But it's does not work with specify queue-name.

Comment: Well, did you register a handler for SendGeneratedPasswordResetCode?

Comment: When I register a handler for Job it's add this work to default queue. Already this is real problem. I want to add specify queue.

Answer (score 22):

You can also specify the queue you want your job to be placed onto by setting the `Job` objects `queue` property on construct:

```
class SendGeneratedPasswordResetCode implements ShouldQueue
{
    // Rest of your class before the construct

    public function __construct(ICodeNotifier $codeNotifier)
    {
        $this->queue = 'SMS'; // This states which queue this job will be placed on.
        $this->codeNotifier = $codeNotifier;
    }

    // Rest of your class after construct
```

You then do not need to provide the `->onQueue()` method on each implementation/usage of this job, as the `Job` class itself will do it for you.

*I have tested this in Laravel 5.6*

Answer (score 2):

This is now covered in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dispatching-to-a-particular-queue

The preferred method is to explicitly call `onQueue(...)` within the constructor of the job:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Jobs;
 
 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 
class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->onQueue('processing');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling onQueue in the wrong place

**should be like below**

```php
dispatch(new YourJob())->onQueue('my_queue');
```

to make it work

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=my_queue
```